# Not a valid month error in UNIX although running successfully in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT fap_inr_idr
  FROM aud_owner.to_cop_msg_aud
 WHERE fap_inr_idr IN
          (SELECT fap_inr_idr
             FROM aud_owner.to_cnf_pye_bse
            WHERE lod_tmp <
                  TO_TIMESTAMP (
                     SYSDATE - NUMTODSINTERVAL (NVL (455, 455), 'DAY')));
```

The query working successfully in Oracle but giving error:

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

in UNIX.

Comment: Oracle is a **database**, while UNIX is an **operating system**. Therefore, you're comparing two different things. I presume that NLS settings are different so - before running that query on UNIX, run `alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy'` and see what happens.

Comment: An error message with the code `ORA-[some_number]` is an Oracle error message. Your question has **absolutely nothing** to do with Unix - or with PL/SQL for that matter (or with database administration either). I will change your tags so they don't mislead others, but for the question itself, I will let you re-word it. As Littlefoot said, this is almost surely caused by your negligent use of implicit conversions, using mismatched format models between `date` and `timestamp`. What happens if you simply remove the `to_timestamp` wrapper (which is probably not needed)?

Comment: What is the data type of column `lod_tmp`?

Comment: _The query working successfully in Oracle_ What does that sentence mean? Do you mean that you execute the query from [SQL*Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Plus)? Or are you using [SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqldeveloper-landing.html)? Or [Toad](https://www.quest.com/products/toad-for-oracle/)? And how do you execute the query from UNIX? Have you written a [shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script)? Please [edit] your question and post answers to my questions.